# nucleation site for fluid vaporization in barometer

Tags: vacuum

I know that in a fluid column barometer, the void at the top is filled with the fluid's vapor at its vapor pressure, so is it necessary for there to be a nucleation site here to allow the fluid to vaporize?

I ask because I am making a low pressure barometer that will operate t-ed in to an experimental vacuum chamber, and using vacuum oil as the fluid. Should measure between ~0 and 1kPa.

I am finding that if I completely fill the column with oil, then the fluid level does not drop, it holds all the way at the top. However, if I leave just a tiny bubble in the column, then as I re-orientate the column upright, the bubble expands as the fluid drops and the level indicates a reasonable pressure to be found in the system.

Does this sound right? With no nucleation site, how can the fluid vaporize to fill the void at the top?

Answer (score 0):

Nucleation is not the only way vaporization can occur. At the surface of the liquid, molecules can break away from their liquid-liquid interactions and enter the vapor phase.